# How to upload few images for one post on django using formset

Tags: django

I am a newbie in django and have some problems during uploading post with multiple images. Post is created, but images are not. I am trying to use formset, but images were not uploaded, errors were not occured. Some source code is below. Please help. Thank you.

MODELS
PostImage:

```
    class PostImage(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Название публикации")
```

VIEWS

```
    @login_required
def post(request):

    ImageFormSet = modelformset_factory(PostImage, form=ImageForm, extra=3)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        postForm = PostForm(request.POST)
        formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES,
                               queryset=PostImage.objects.none())

        if postForm.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            post_form = postForm.save(commit=False)
            post_form.user = request.user
            post_form.words = len(post_form.body.split())
            post_form.reading_time = int(ceil(post_form.words/120))
            post_form.save()

            # for form in formset.cleaned_data:
            #     if form:
            #         image = form["image"]
            #         photo = PostImage(post=post_form, image=image, user=request.user)
            #         photo.save()
            images = formset.save(commit=False)
            for image in images:
                image.post = post_form
                image.image = image['image']
                image.user = request.user
                image.save()
            formset.save()
            formset.save_m2m()
            return redirect('blog:home')
        else:
            print(postForm.errors, formset.errors)
    else:
        postForm = PostForm()
        formset = ImageFormSet(queryset=PostImage.objects.none())
    return render(request, 'blog/create_post.html',
                  {'postForm': postForm, 'formset': formset})
```

HTML

```
                   <form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    {% csrf_token %}
  {{ formset.management_form }}

  {% for form in formset %}
<div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-9">

                            <!-- Form fields - post.reading_time -->
                            <input  type="file"
                                    placeholder="Картинка"
                                    class="form-control"
                                    name="image"
                                    value="{{ form.image.value|default:"" }}">

                        </div>
                    </div>
              {% endfor %}
                  ...
```

Comment: You don't have a ImageField on your model, so the form doesn't know what do to with the images. You will need to setup your django media config and add a `models.ImageField` yo your `PostImage` model.

Comment: I have this ImageField, but I didn't include because post has limits of attached code. Model class PostImage(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Название публикации")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_images/', verbose_name="Картинка")
    is_main = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Основная картинка")